# How to stop input overflowing via stdin

Tags: c, memory-management, malloc, stdin, fgets

My program is supposed to accept input via stdin and store the string into an array of size `SIZE`.

My problem occurs when I enter 7 or more values; the values that go beyond the buffer size are still used as the program runs in a loop, constatly filling up `buf` with what is left in stdin (at least, that is how I think it is working).

```
#define SIZE 8

char *readLine(char *buf, size_t size) {
    printf("$ ");
    fgets(buf, size, stdin);
    return buf;
}

int main() {
    char *buf = malloc(SIZE * sizeof(char));
    
    for (;;) {
        readLine(buf, SIZE);
        printf("> %s", buf);
    }   
}
```

The output I have, testing an input size of 6, 7, and 8 respectively:

```
$ abcdef
> abcdef
$ abcdefg
> abcdefg$ > 
$ abcdefgh
> abcdefg$ > h
```

The things I don't understand:

- Why does the 7th value make the program's output appear strange? I thought the 7th character plus the null character would work correctly?
- Why does `buf` fill up with values beyond the size of `SIZE` (8 in this case)?

From this, is there a simple change/addition I could make to achieve what I want to make?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why does the 7th value make the program's output appear strange? I thought the 7th character plus the null character would work correctly?

`fgets` doesn't read the excessive input (beyond the  buffer size you provided excluding one byte space for null byte). So the character `h` is left in the input stream and is then consumed by your next call to `fgets` - that read `h` and the newline char `\n`. Upon reading newline char, `fgets` terminates reading further input.

> Why does buf fill up with values beyond the size of SIZE (8 in this case)?

It doesn't. As noted, the leftover input is read and thus it gives such an appearance.

> From this, is there a simple change/addition I could make to achieve what I want to make?

You can check if the buffer read by `fgets` has newline char; if not, read & ignore the leftover bytes from the input stream.

You can do:

```
void discard(const char *buf)
{
    if(strchr(buf, '\n') == NULL) {
        /* No newline found, so read & discard everything.
        while(getchar() != '\n');
    }
}

char *readLine(char *buf, size_t size) {
    printf("$ ");
    if (fgets(buf, size, stdin) != NULL) {
        discard(buf);
    }
    return buf;
}
```

Comment: Ah, thanks for clearing that up. But on your last point, assuming there ins't a newline and the input is, say, 12 characters long, how do I make it *ignore* the rest of the text (beyond the 7th character)? Do I work out the 8th index and make it = '/0'? Does that ignore the rest or something? Being able to ignore the rest of the input beyond `size` is what I have been trying to figure out.

Comment: @zfac122 Updated with an example how you could achieve.